# Customize the Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

I need to **Customize the information Area in Ms Dynamics CRM**.   [image]

Which means i need to Add one more link **after that General,Administration,then I need to add new Link** in **campaign new Form**.If I click that Link i need to open new form.How to do this in microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That area is reserved to list the form tabs, is not possible to customize.
But you can add a link just under *Common*, use the form editor and edit the navigation section, you can add a link to a Web Resource or to an external link